# Editing multicam video on Linux

Tags: linux, video-editing

Multicam is a feature where you combine several video clips together (for example, an Internet band whose members record his own instrument at home, then mix all videos of the members into one single video), with all video arranged in one screen, and all audio tracks mixed together.

I have tried Cinelerra and Kdenlive, but it seems that they don't support that.

Can I do multicam editing with those, or any other Linux program?

Comment: If there wouldn't be any answer I tell you a head-on method: 1) by ffmpeg/mencoder/mplayer make a set of images & get audiotrack from any videofile; 2) mix images by ImageMagick; 3) mix audio by sox; 4) collect it together by ffmpeg/mencoder.

Comment: @Eddy_Em The images dumped from the videos will use a large amount of disk space, and if the fps between the videos is different, how to sync these images will be another problem.

Comment: AFAIK, there's still no such soft. But that would be a great patch to ffmpeg if someone "teach" it to compose multiply videos "on the fly". As for sync, ffmpeg would reconstruct images in needed fps.

Comment: Neither the question nor the answers seem to address to task of syncing all the video's and audio together, do they?

Answer (score 3):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/)  handles multicam. [Manual entry here.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/multicam.html)

> Ever wanted to do multicam editing with Blender? Now you can and it is
>   mindbogglingly easy:
>
> - Add your input strips on channels say 1 to 4 (you can use as many you like, interface get's a little bit clumky if you have more than
>     10, see below).
> - Sync the strips up. There is no automatic sync feature in Blender, but you can open two viewer windows, choose one camera as the master
>     channel and sync the other against them just by looking at the
>     movement of legs or light flashes (depending of the show, you want to
>     edit). We might add automatic sync feature based on global brightness
>     of the video frames in the future. (Syncing based on the audio tracks,
>     like most commercial applications do, isn't very clever, since the
>     speed of sound is only around 340 metres per second and if you have
>     one of you camera 30 meters away, which isn't uncommon, you are
>     already 2-3 frames off. Which *is* noticeable...)
> - Build small resolution proxies (25%) on all your input video strips.
> - Use meta strips, so that every input camera fits in exactly one channel.
> - Add a viewer window for every input channel and put it into 25% proxy display mode (I suggest to line them up on the left side on top
>     of each other, but just do, whatever pleases your personal habits)
> - Add a large viewer window for the final output and let it run on full resolution.
> - Add a multicam selector effect strip *above* all the channel tracks
> - Enlarge it, so that it covers the whole running time of your show (just change it's length or drag the right handle, the former is
>     probably easier, since you can just type in a very large number and
>     you are done)
> - Cross you fingers :) (that's important :) )
> - Select the multicam strip, if you take a look at the strip options (N-key), you will notice, that multicam is a rather simple effect
>     strip: it just takes a selected channel as it's input. That's all. The
>     magic comes with the convenient keyboard layout: when you select
>     multicam, the keys 1-0 are mapped to a python handler, that does a cut
>     on the multicam and changes it's input.
> - So: you select the multicam strip, you start playback and hit the keys 1-4 while watching your show.
> - You'll end up with a small multicam selector strip for every cut.

Comment: could you summarize the content of the link which would help for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Try Synfig.

[SYNFIG Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/)

There is no reason why you couldn't composite several videos into the one frame (all videos in the one frame) and render it out as a single video.  Though you might have to convert the original videos into image sequences first. But I'm certain it can be done.  Synfig is not a compositing package (it's more designed for cartoon style animation) though it can be used to do what you're describing.

If you have to edit the video afterwards try openshot.

[OpenShot Video Editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com/)

Comment: Dump video to image sequences first, then ImageMagick can also does the job to compose them together. If there are any tools can directly operate with videos, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found that multicam is supported by [Vivia](http://vivia-video.org/screenshots.html)

Also [Kdenlive can be used for this](http://www.addlime.com/blog/video/kdenlive-multicam-editing-workflow/)
since version 0.9. Ubuntu contains earlier version 8, so you need to add PPA ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release

Also you can create videos with AviSynth scripts:

```
a = AVISource ("video1.avi")
b = AVISource ("video2.avi")
return stackhorizontal (a,b)
```

Editors that defenetelly hasn't support: VrtualDub, Kino, Avidemux, Blender (it has 'multicam' but it is 3D modeling).

Maybe in feature Pitivi will support multicam (it is in roadmap Google_Summer_of_Code).